# Properties of determinant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> If **A** is an m×n matrix and **B** is an n×m matrix, then **det(AB) = det(BA)**.

The above is false as **A** and **B** are not square matrices. However, how do i go about proving it?

Comment: It isn't necessarily, if $m\ne n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yup, my bad. The above is not true if A and B are not square matrices. However, how do i go about proving it?

Comment: One way round the determinant is zero, the other way round it may or may not be zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just find the simplest counter example, consider

$$\det\left(\left[\begin{array}{&&} a&b\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{&}c\\d\end{array}\right]\right)=\det\left(\left[ac+bd\right]\right)=ac+bd$$

and

$$\det\left(\left[\begin{array}{&}c\\d\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{&&} a&b\end{array}\right]\right)=\det\left(\left[\begin{array}{&&}ca&cb\\da&db\end{array}\right]\right)=cadb-dacb=0$$

So
$$\det(AB)=\det(BA)$$
is in general not true.

EDIT: Since the OP has changed his/her question, I need to add the following:

However,
$$\det(AB)\ne \det(BA)$$
is also in general not true.

Consider the special case
$$ac+bd=0$$